# No certificates when trying to add SSL Bindings for Azure Web App

Tags: azure, ssl, https, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create an SSL Binding for an Azure Web App that is a host for an API App.

After navigating to "Custom domains and SSL" for the web app in question, I have added a custom domain name "admin.api.foo.com" and uploaded the PFX for my wildcard certificate (*.foo.com) and it displays in the list in the "Certificates" section.

I think the next step is to create an SSL Binding. So I go to the "SSL bindings" section and I can select the hostname "admin.api.foo.com" from the drop down but in the dropdown for the certificate there is only one option "choose certificate". Why doesn't my wildcard cert show up in this drop down?

Comment: also running into this issue, I'm not using a subdomain though, anyone else having this problem?  I'm using an external domain and an azure purchased SSL certificate.  I'm positive the domain on the certificate matches my hostname.

Comment: To add to SaltySub's answer, if you upgraded your tier from Free/Shared to Basic just before purchasing the certificate, you may need to log out and back in so that the SSL Settings tab updates and allows you to make the selection to import the certificate.

Comment: I disabled and "HTTPS Only" in "TLS/SSL settings", then added the private key cert then re-enabled "HTTPS Only".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to register a subdomain of subdomain.

Instead of using admin.api.foo.com I started using adminapi.foo.com. It started showing up in the drop down.

Answer (score 7):

As of Feb 15 2017, you may encounter a similar issue of "No certificates match the selected hostname"... even if you purchased the certificate from Azure itself. What worked was clicking "Import App Service Certificate" first. Then you can add the SSL binding (this is for non-wildcard, will bind root and www domain). Cheers.

[image]

Comment: You are my hero. I can't believe how many stupid hours I wasted on this dumb user interface issue. Thank-you StackOverflow.

Comment: @Doug no worries, keep in mind as well that after importing you need to add bindings for both the www and non-www domain name (in general for non-wildcard SSLs especially(?) if the SSL was not purchased from Azure).