# Azure SSL binding "Create Certificate" drop down menu has no options

Tags: azure, https, ssl-certificate, web-hosting

I bought a cert from godaddy yesterday for my domain that's running on Azure web hosting.  Upon installing, I had to upgrade my hosting plan to something that accepts SSL certs.  So I upgraded to basic.  That went fine.  I followed some online steps to creating CSR from my local IIS and then installing the cert in IIS and then exporting the .pfx file.  That seemed to went okay.  I got a cert with .pfx.  I went to my Azure dashboard and went to custom domains and SSL and uploaded the certs.  Didn't get any errors.  However, when I try to bind it, the drop down menu doesn't have the cert.  I did an online search and I found this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787314/no-certificates-when-trying-to-add-ssl-bindings-for-azure-web-app) post but I'm not doing a sub-domain.  I called godaddy support but they can't help since, rightfully, they ask me what is it about the cert that Azure doesn't like?  Since I have no error messages, I have no answer to that question.

So I'm sending this SOS (Save Our Saturday) for help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  The issue was that there are too many inconsistent tutorial out there.  In one version, they ask you to go to mmc and use the snapin certificate and export it the cert that way.  That's wrong.  Always use IIS for exporting the cert.  I don't' always play sys admin, but when I do, it's a reminder of why I didn't become one.

Comment: hi Zuzlx, how did you manage to solve it? I tried to import and export from IIS, but the certificate is still disabled.