# Azure : No certificates match the selected hostname even it has the certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate, azure-app-service-plans

I've already set up my custom wildcard Domain which is purchased along with the SSL Certificate. I also set up those with my Azure App.

It is the restriction that I need to delete the certificate in order to move my azure app from one subscription to another subscription. So I delete the certificate then moved my azure app to another subscription.

Now If I tried to add the certificate again, I couldn't able to get any certificate which is available for my domain(wildcard).

I tried with Adding the certificates like

1. Custom Domain -> Add Binding
   which results as **No certificates match the selected hostname**
2. SSL Settings-> Add SSL Binding
   The same results as **No certificates match the selected hostname**
3. SSL Settings-Private Certificate -> Import Private Certificate
   which results as **No valid certificate found**

I found this similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787314/no-certificates-when-trying-to-add-ssl-bindings-for-azure-web-app) but unfortunately, it's not working for me. I think is related to some UI bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you need to delete the certificate in order to move your azure app from one subscription to another subscription. I suppose that you include an SSL certificate that you purchased externally and uploaded to the app. **You only need to upload the certificate as your original uploading your SSL certificate** to the web app again in the new subscription after moving the web app.

About the error message: No certificates match the selected hostname. You need to check these:

Firstly, you must have a custom domain linked to the Azure Web App in order to configure an SSL BINDING. Secondly, the domain for which the certificate is created for, must match the custom domain.

Ref: [My SSL Certificate doesn’t work on Azure Websites](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2014/12/01/my-ssl-certificate-doesnt-work-on-azure-websites/)

Comment: thanks for the response. As I mentioned in the comments I've custom domain which was purchased from Godaddy along with the SSL certificate then linked to the Azure web app and configured the SSL binding works great. But after deleting and moving the services to other subscription, I couldn't able to add the certificate which is already linked to my custom domain.

Comment: Before you move web app, for a 3rd party cert, you need to delete the binding and delete Private Certificates stored from any applications that are in use. Then you could upload the SSL cert again after moving the web app. If that is not you have done, you could try to move back to that original resource group first, and then follow correct order to move across subscriptions again. Refer to [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/8390#issuecomment-398888615).

Comment: Here you are mentioning about that **you could upload the SSL cert again after moving the web app** That's the problem which I'm facing, do I need to export the certificate before moving, then upload it [manually](https://pratapgowda.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/azure-portal.png) after the move ?

Comment: You can try it if you could not add SSL binding now. Honestly, I have not tested this, but per my links before, you need to export the certificate before moving, then upload it manually after the move.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you would move app service certificate to another subscription.

The [limitations for moving App Service resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#app-service-limitations) apply to uploaded certificates, not App Service Certificates. You can move App Service Certificates to a new resource group or subscription without limitations.

> When moving a Web App across subscriptions, the following limitations apply:
>
> 1.The destination resource group must not have any existing App Service resources.
>
> Note:App Service resources include:Web Apps,App Service plans,Uploaded or imported SSL certificates,App Service Environments
>
> 2.**All App Service resources in the resource group must be moved together**.
>
> 3.App Service resources can only be moved from the resource group in which they were originally created. If an App Service resource is no longer in its original resource group, it must be moved back to that original resource group first, and then it can be moved across subscriptions.

If you want to use your App Service certificate in a different subscription in Azure, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/02/24/creating-a-local-pfx-copy-of-app-service-certificate/).

Comment: I purchased the domain from GoDaddy, but now I couldn't able to select my certificate from the Azure portal, but my custom domain is still working properly

Comment: So, where you purchase ssl certificate ? The error means that you do not move the valid certificate to another subscription, so you could try my link to move it.

Comment: I purchase the SSL certificate from GoDaddy as a wildcard SSL Certificate. Once after moving my app service from one sub to another sub, I couldn't able to add my SSL Binding (Certificate not found issue)

Comment: Have you tried to upload certificate to the other sub as before?  Steps like this [article](https://yaplex.com/blog/ssl-domain-certificate-azure-website-from-godaddy).

Comment: The reason why your domain work but your cert not  is because you need to manually add certificate to your webapp.

Comment: But before deleting the certification, I can able to view those certificates and able to bind the SSL in the Azure portal itself. At that time I do not manually add the certificate (by using upload certificate)

Comment: If you're using an SSL certificate on the primary domain name of a GoDaddy shared hosting account, you do not need to generate a CSR, godaddy will do it for you. But after you purchase an SSL certificate, and activate the SSL credit, if you move to another sub, you may need to generate a certificate signing request (CSR) for the website's domain name before you can request the SSL certificate. Refer to this [article](https://sg.godaddy.com/help/generate-a-csr-certificate-signing-request-5343).